# ERROR: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services or higher

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssis-2016

I have VS2015 Community and SQL Server 2016 Developer installed. Using the MSFT link, I've ensured to download the latest version of SSDT, which appears to install without error (though, Integration Services do not show in the SQL Configuration Manager). Using previously validated projects that creates and executes SSIS packages, I cannot get the same code to work with the current setup.

The error showing when I debug:

> Component: SSIS.Pipeline
>   Error: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services or higher.

I've uninstalled, reinstalled, repaired, modified, etc., but cannot get the package to build and execute. Has anyone seen similar issues with the setup mentioned?

Comment: But did you install Integration Services? Is the service running?

Comment: @JacobH When I've run SSDT, IS has been selected every time and no errors are displayed. IS do not, however, show in the SQL Configuration Manager, so I'd absolutely concede that the install is failing, though I don't know why.

Comment: I would just try installing with the SQL Server installer instead. If that doesn't work, check the Windows logs for errors.

Comment: @JacobH link in SQL installer sends you to the SSDT download page, which is where I've taken that installer from several times.

Comment: Are SQL Server 2016 and related project even compatible with VS 2015?

Comment: Download site says the latest allows for VS2015-SQL2016 compatibility. The project has been compiled and works in VS2017, however, the present code base/release cycle needs to be built in 2015 (business requirement)

Comment: Did you check the windows logs?

Comment: Nothing in the logs from the install. Running the package logs a generic SQLISPackage130 error id12291, which just indicates failure. Have to catch it in the debugger to see the error message about x64 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding

You need to install SQL Server and make sure to select Integration Services. Then run DTExec.exe from the new SQL server installation folder.

Comment: In 2016, IS are installed through a separate MSI, SSDT. When you try to install from SQL installer, it takes you to the latest version of SSDT.

Comment: After further review, I found the IS option in the SQL2016 installer. That, along with the Client Tools SDK, allowed the packages to execute. The documentation from MSFT pointed towards the SSDT installer, but SQL still holds the components.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. I ended up installing SQL Server 2017, SSMS 17.4 and VS 2017, SSDT for VS2017 and successfully run my packages FINALLY! It looks like SQL server and SSDT/VS version has to be "matched". Not sure if they have to be the same version though. But this is quite annoying.