# SSIS script task error on sql job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i want to run a ssis package from sql job 
sql version is 2016
ssis package first was 2013 and have error with message as below

> Started:  6:19:50 AM  Error: 2018-02-10 06:19:50.57     Code: 0x00000003     Source: Script Task Script Task     Description: There
>   was an exception while loading Script Task from XML:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications Version=14.0.0.0
>   Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications Version=14.0.0.0
>   Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.b__1b()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.MtaExecution.Run(Action
>   action)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.CleanUp()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSTADenaliScriptProject(XmlElement
>   elemProj IDTSInfoEvents events)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement
>   elemProj IDTSInfoEvents events)    WRN: Assembly binding logging
>   is turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind failure logging set the
>   registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to
>   1.  Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.  To turn this feature off remove the
>   registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].  End Error 
>   Error: 2018-02-10 06:19:50.58     Code: 0x00000003     Source: Script
>   Task      Description: The Script Task is corrupted.

then i install new version (2015) and now i have this error

> 02/10/2018
>   08:41:20,SSIS,Error,1,WIN2016-SQL2016\SQL2016,SSIS,SSIS,,Executed as
>   user: WIN2016-SQL2016\Administrator. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) 2016
>   Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:41:20 AM  Error:
>   2018-02-10 08:41:20.59     Code: 0xC000F427     Source: Script Task
>   Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools
>   you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher. 
>   End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

Comment: ssis package is simple and there is only empty Script Task
when i change it to excel source job runs without error

Comment: 2013 and 2015 are not versions of SQL Server. Do you mean SQL Server Data Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the package on the real server. Some things do not work right in the simulators.

Comment: after more work on SSIS problems i found that this error is for installation. if you do not install ssis in sql server installation this error be arised. now i am sure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123182/error-to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install-s

Answer (score 0):

Anush,
Based on your last error, try running the SSIS package as 32 bit instead of 64 bit.

Comment: the error only happen when i add a Script Task to SSIS package

Comment: Do you have more than 1 version of SSIS running on your machine?

Comment: no, I uninstall 2013 version. now i only have SSIS 2015 and sql 2016 . i target the sql 2016 in my package too

Comment: Open up MS Sql Server config.  Look to be sure you have the highest version of SSIS running.  The error message indicates that there is a conflict in versions, and that you are pointing to an earlier one

Comment: You can also try forcing the package to run under the installation you intend with a command line that looks similar to this: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /f "C:\SSIS\Load_Files.dtsx" /ConfigFile "C:\SSIS\loadFiles_SSIS_Configuration.dtsconfig

Comment: try searching for this: SQLServerManager13

Comment: i find it but i can't find what SSIS  version is running

Comment: OK, in the app search (charm) type services.  When the services display (it may take a while depending on how much you have running) scroll over to SQL look for SQL Server Integration Services -- see if you have 1 or more running. if you have 2 running, kill the older one.

Comment: consider that job is run the package but when i add a Script Task to SSIS package then ERROR happen

Comment: Yes, you're in a confict between data tools/libraries. We're trying to determine which one.

Comment: I search for it but i cant find any SQL Server Integration Services

Comment: See that second error message you posted: it says _SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 13.0.1601.5 for 32-bit _ That tells you which version of SSIS it's trying to run in

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found it related to script tasks that were created in an earlier version of SSIS BI project that are not automatically converted.

Here is what I did to upgrade them. It might be a bit different for you but should give you some idea where to start.

**Step 1.** BACKUP. Make a backup of your SSIS projects and dtsx files.

**Step 2.** Create a new SSIS solution. Make sure that it indicates that in the VS Solution Explorer toolbox (see image 1).

**Step 3.** Check for the latest version of Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll you have under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server[Version NO]\DTS\Tasks. Make a note of that number.

**Step 4.** Open the dtsx file in a text editor (Notepad, Notepad++, etc.)

**Step 5.** Search for VSTAMajorVersion and change to the version you noted in step 3. See image 2.

**Step 6.** Replace the Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll reference in the file to the one you found in step 3.

**Step 7.** Add the dtsx files to the newly created SSIS solution and try to edit the sciprt tasks.

**Step 8.** Save and update your SQL Server Agent jobs to execute the newly created dtsx files.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]